# Call to a member function move() on array

Tags: laravel

```
 $files = $request->file('file');
        foreach ($files as $file){
            $filename = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $location = public_path('uploads/'.$filename);

            $request->file->move(public_path('/uploads'), end($filename));

            $filename_arr = [];
            array_push($filename_arr, $filename);
            $filename = json_encode($filename_arr);
            $upload->filename = $filename;
        }
```

I have checked several others codes online but they seem to be working fine but mine keeps saying that move cannot be used on an array

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `$request->file` array instead of `$file` element of the array. So, change this:

```
$request->file->move(public_path('/uploads'), end($filename));
```

To:

```
$file->move(public_path('/uploads'), end($filename));
```